# beforeAll and beforeEach suite instead of spec

Tags: node.js, angular, jasmine, protractor

I am writing some e2e tests using protractor 5. What I am trying to achieve is to execute whole tests which shared setup, and specific setup (for groups of tests).

I got following code:

Base.ts:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    console.log("before all base");
});

beforeEach(()=> {
    console.log("before each base");
});

afterEach(() => {
    console.log("after each base")
});

afterAll(() => {
    console.log("after all base");
});
```

TestSuite1.ts:

```
require('./Base');

describe("test suite 1", () => {

    beforeAll(() => {
        console.log("before all 1");
    });

    beforeEach(()=> {
        console.log("before each 1");
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        console.log("after each 1")
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        console.log("after all 1");
    });


    it("test 1", () => {
        console.log("test 1 1");
    });

    it("test 2", () => {
        console.log("test 1 2");
    });
});
```

TestSuite2.ts:

```
require('./Base');

describe("test suite 2", () => {    
    it("test 1", () => {
        console.log("test 2 1");
    });

    it("test 2", () => {
        console.log("test 2 2");
    });
});
```

and conf.ts:

```
var testsTimeout = 3600000;

export let config: Config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['test/TestSuite1.js', 'test/TestSuite2.js'],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  noGlobals: true,
  allScriptsTimeout: testsTimeout
};
```

I would like to get following output:

```
before all base
before each base

before all 1
before each 1
test 1 1
after each 1
before each 1
test 1 2
after each 1
after all 1

after each base
before each base

test 2 1
test 2 2

after each base
after all base
```

Unfornatelly my `before/after all` and `before/after each` are grouped together and prints as follows:

```
before all base
before all 1

before each base
before each 1
test 1 1
after each 1
after each base

.before each base
before each 1
test 1 2
after each 1
after each base

.after all 1

before each base
test 2 1
after each base

.before each base
test 2 2
after each base

.after all base
```

Is it possible to get execution flow which I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, your function will be executed before/after everything in your suite.

Idea is to put `beforeAll()` `afterAll()` or `beforeEach()` `afterEach()` into protractor's configuration file - into `onPrepare()` section.

This might look like this:

```
module.exports.config = {
    //somewhere in your config
    onPrepare: function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            //This will be executed before EVERY 'it' in each specfile
        })

        beforeAll(function () {
            //This will be executed before EVERY 'describe' in each specfile (even before nested describes)
        })
    }
}
```

Also check other options in protractor config: `onComplete()` `afterLaunch()` - they might better work for you instead jasmine functions

You might want to look on jasmine reporters, in case you need to somehow work with test name, test result, suite result, and might be good alternative to before/after functions . They are pretty easy to create and use, check this:

https://jasmine.github.io/edge/custom_reporter.html

Comment: I just checked your answer. Unfornatelly adding ```beforeAll``` in configuration file, causes execute that method ONLY before whole suite. In other words, execution flow is:  ```config beforeAll``` -> ```describe 1 ``` -> ```it 1 1``` -> ```it 1 2``` -> ```describe 2``` -> ```it 2 1``` -> ```it 2 2``` -> ```config afterAll```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is how Protractor is designed to work. There was an issue which was raised to track the scenario where a `beforeAll()` runs before any `beforeEach()` in parent describe block

Check the complete [discussion here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/873).

> With the current implementation (if I understand correctly), it only
>   really makes sense to have a single beforeAll, and this should either
>   be outside of any describe block, or at the top of the outermost
>   describe block. i.e. It would make no sense for my 2nd beforeAll to be
>   located where it is.

Comment: So there is no way to run part of code before group of tests (surrounded by ```describe```)?